# What age range is a girl called 少女?

Tags: grammar

I was wondering does this have a specific age range in mind and all? Can women up to their 20s be called this and all?

Comment: Well, it is not opinion-based technically — they agree that there is no agreed definition...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will depend on who you ask, but that said up until and including 18 it's definitely reasonable. 19 and 20 probably, too. After that until 25 I think it's uncommon. From 26 on it would be very unusual. After 28 I think the listener will assume you are using it intentionally, as in to make a specific point about someone's 少女-ness (although they are clearly no longer a 少女 in its usual meaning).